# Program type already present: BuildConfig

Tags: android, android-multidex

I'm trying to generate a release build but im not able because of mutidex issues my project has all the multidex enabled and dependencies added

The error i'm receiving is :

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForRelease

Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
```

and aslo:

```
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: com.myapp.BuildConfig
```

Comment: Do you have library module which has the same package name as the app module? can you updated your question with build.gradle file?

Comment: Place content of both Gradle file

Comment: @sagar yes i have a library with the same package name, i think that what generate this problem, what the solution for this ?

Comment: was the answer useful?

Comment: You can see this response
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26531074/4097495
in my case solve with this suggestion.
my app and my module have same package name

Comment: mine has unique package names but still get this error

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You are getting this error because you a have library module which has the same package name as the app module.

The solution would be to change package name of your library module. You can follow the accepted answer in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package) which describes how to change the package name in android studio.

Comment: If this did not work for you , try doing a `./gradle clean` on the android project after you renamed the library.

Answer (score 18):

In my case It was happening when I try to run older project on new installed Android studio
The problem solved by running `Build->Clean Project`

**Note:** As friends say on comments this is solution for a flutter project

Comment: Worked for me when building a flutter app and converted to androidx

Comment: I had this issue when struggling with a flutter project. I cleaned it while the android part was opened.

Comment: in flutter , this is the solution

Answer (score 12):

I solved this error enabling multiDexEnabled in the `build.gradle` of my app's module:

```
defaultConfig { 
    ...
    ...
    ...

    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: Enabling or disabling?

Comment: @red-devil sorry, my fault. It's enabling, so `multiDexEnabled true` (will fix the typo).

Answer (score 7):

Error: Program type already present: somemodule/BuildConfig

**Cause**

In my case I had a (hidden) circular dependency which Android Studio did not find:

1. `testutils/build.gradle` uses `implementation project(':somemodule')`
2. `somemodule/build.gradle` had `androidTestImplementation project(":testutils")

**Solution**

- in my case the second dependency was not neccessary so I removed it

Answer (score 5):

Just goto **tools>Flutter>Flutter clean** in android studio.
It'll resolve the issue. (If you are working with flutter)

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem after an android x upgrade in android studio. To fix this I went to File->Open and opened the android folder within my current flutter project. I was then able to go to Build->Clean Project as suggested by @Seymour Mammadli.

Hopefully this helps someone with the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the issue building a **Flutter** application and I resolved it following the **official guide**:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

You simply have to:

0. (**Android:** Go to Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX 
 (If you are on a **Flutter** project, to migrate the module, you have to go to Tools > Flutter > Open for Editing in Android Studio

1. (**Both**) Modify the module-level build.gradle file to enable multidex and add the multidex library as a dependency, as shown here:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

2. (**non-Flutter**) If you do not override the Application class, edit your manifest file to set **android:name** in the <application> tag as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

2. (**Flutter**) If you do not override the Application class, edit your manifest file to set **android:name** in the <application> tag as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name=".App" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

3.(**Flutter**) Create a custom class under project/android/app/src/main/[java or kotlin folder]/[your/package/appName]
kotlin version: **App.kt**

```
package your.package.appName

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import android.content.Context
import androidx.multidex.MultiDex

class App : FlutterApplication() {

    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base)
        MultiDex.install(this)
    }

}
```

java version: **App.java**

```
package your.package.appName;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import android.content.Context;
import androidx.multidex.MultiDex;

public class App extends FlutterApplication {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

}
```

4. (**Both**) Celebrate if you did it!! :D

For more info, check out the official guide ;)
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error. This type of application is not as generic as we do except. IN my application development I was using the below mentioned dependencies

```
  youtube_player_flutter: ^6.1.0+7
  webview_flutter: ^0.3.20+2
```

since `youtube_player_flutter` internally it makes use of `webview_flutter` as one of the dependencies. I removed the dependencies `webview_flutter` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

try add packageBuildConfig(false) in your library module:

```
android{
  ...
  packageBuildConfig(false)
}
```

Comment: This should be now, ```buildFeatures {
    buildConfig = false
}```, right?

Answer (score 2):

Open with Android studio

1. Build > Clean Project
2. build > Build bundle (bundle / apk)

Build with android studio work for me. instead of with gradlew console

Answer (score 1):

go to android folder and fire the below command

./gradlew clean

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Developing a plugin), doing these steps worked:

- `cd example/android` (`example` is the project path)
- `./gradlew app:clean`
- `cd ..; flutter clean; flutter packages get`

Answer (score 0):

This issue can also occur if your `buildDir` is the same for two or more modules in a project.

Comment: it is not correct, he must enable the muti dex  in the gradle

Comment: I had this exact issue and I solved it by changing `buildDir` to be unique per module. Enabling multi dex had no impact whatsoever. I'm not saying this will solve OP's issue. I simply added this answer in case it helps other people that come across this thread in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Change your package name, ex:

Your current package name:

***com.example.appname***

to:

***com.example.appname.app***

Answer (score 0):

I meet the error when i adding flutter to existing project, the message indicates that AndroidX causes the problem.

when i modify the  AndroidX at the bootom of  *flutter_module/pubspec.yaml*

```
AndroidX:false
```

and try again , it works;