# React Native: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I haven't change anything and now my project doesn't work. I have been getting this error since this morning:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.

I have tried to implement multiDexEnabled. In my build.gradle I added the multiDexEnabled like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myApp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.3"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
```

This are my dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation project(':react-native-video')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-touch-id')
    implementation project(':react-native-picker')
    implementation(project(':react-native-maps')) {
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'

    implementation project(':react-native-keychain')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')
    implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'
}
```

Also I change my Application for MultiDexApplication like so:

```
import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;

public class MainApplication extends MultiDexApplication implements ReactApplication {
...
}
```

And this is the stacktrace of the error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
      at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
      at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
      at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
      at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
      ... 29 more
  Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
      at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.D8MainDexListTransform.transform(D8MainDexListTransform.kt:127)
      at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
      at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
      at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
      ... 41 more
  Caused by: com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList$MainDexListException: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzsh
      at com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList.generate(D8MainDexList.java:87)
      at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.D8MainDexListTransform.transform(D8MainDexListTransform.kt:114)
      ... 44 more
  Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzsh
      at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.resolveClassConflictImpl(ProgramClassCollection.java:64)
      at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.lambda$create$0(ProgramClassCollection.java:25)
      at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.create(ProgramClassCollection.java:24)
      at com.android.tools.r8.graph.LazyLoadedDexApplication$Builder.build(LazyLoadedDexApplication.java:121)
      at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:122)
      at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:86)
      at com.android.tools.r8.GenerateMainDexList.run(GenerateMainDexList.java:40)
      at com.android.tools.r8.GenerateMainDexList.run(GenerateMainDexList.java:110)
      at com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList.generate(D8MainDexList.java:83)
      ... 45 more

Please help, I don't know what I'm missing.
And thank you for any tip you can give me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio: Error while generating the main dex list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50205825/android-studio-error-while-generating-the-main-dex-list)

Comment: I noticed the duplicated com.google.android.gms:play-services-base so I removed 1 and it didn't help

Comment: Try specifying the versions for play-services-base and play-services-maps rather than using `+`

Comment: Ok, I tried setting google service like this: implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0' I get the same error "Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'."

Comment: Finally my problem was firebase-core. I updated everything to the latest availabre so now I'm using com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4, com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4 and com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0 but I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it working

app/build.gradle

```
    dependencies {
        implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5")
        implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4")
    ...
}
```

build.gradle
and

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Also I have to add that https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#latest_sdk_versions said that the latest for the firebase-core was 16.0.4 but that didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

**Paste this in app.gradle below defaultConfig{}.It worked for me**

`compileOptions {
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}`